# Import only works when module installed using --editable pip flag

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, virtualenv, setuptools

I have [this project on github](https://github.com/queirozfcom/jekyll-utils) that allows me to do some jekyll actions more easily.

When I clone that and install it into my `virtualenv` ( `pip install virtualenv .`) it works fine, but if I just install **without** the `--editable` flag I get these errors when I try to use the commands exposed by [`click`](http://click.pocoo.org/6/):

```
$ jk-config-set-editor Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/felipe/jekyll-utils/jekyll-venv/bin/jk-config-set-editor", line 7, in <module>
from jekyllutils.configs import set_editor
ImportError: No module named 'jekyllutils'
```

[This is my `setup.py` file:](https://github.com/queirozfcom/jekyll-utils/blob/master/setup.py)

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
        name="jekyllutils",
        version='0.1',
        py_modules=['generators'],
        install_requires=[
            'click',
            'python-slugify',
            'appdirs',
            'toml'
        ],
        entry_points='''
        [console_scripts]
        jk-new = jekyllutils.generators:new_post
        jk-edit = jekyllutils.managers:edit_post
        jk-config-set-editor = jekyllutils.configs:set_editor
        jk-config-set-posts-path = jekyllutils.configs:set_path_to_posts_dir
        jk-config-dump-configs = jekyllutils.configs:dump_configs
        jk-config-clear-configs = jekyllutils.configs:clear_configs
    '''

)
```

Anybody has any idea as to why this works when `--editable` is on but not otherwise?

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Comment: nope I just use --editable

Comment: okay, I had to use `find_packages` to fix it

Answer (score 2):

In case anyway runs into this same issue, what worked for me was to use the `find_packages` function to define my packages in `setup.py`

I also had to define static data files using the `package_data` field.

```py
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
        name="jekyllutils",
        version='0.1',
        py_modules=['generators'],
        install_requires=[
            'click',
            'python-slugify',
            'appdirs',
            'toml'
        ],
        entry_points='''
            [console_scripts]
            jk-new = jekyllutils.generators:new_post
            jk-edit = jekyllutils.managers:edit_post
            jk-config-set-editor = jekyllutils.configs:set_editor
            jk-config-set-posts-path = jekyllutils.configs:set_path_to_posts_dir
            jk-config-dump-configs = jekyllutils.configs:dump_configs
            jk-config-clear-configs = jekyllutils.configs:clear_configs
        ''',
        packages=find_packages(),
        package_data={
            "": ["*.txt", "*.json", "*.csv", "*.html"],
        },

)
```